# running Sax parser

Tags: parsing, compilation, sax

Am new to using SAX parser .Can anyone tell me how to run it .and what all are required to run it (jdk )..Can i have a sax parser that can parse both android xml and a normal xml

Answer (score 0):

SAX parsers are implemented by creating a `ContentHandler` object which implements certain callback functions that correspond to events that happen while parsing an XML document.  For example, the `startDocument` method is called when the parser begins parsing the document, and `startElement` is called when it discovers a new tag; similarly, `endElement`, `endDocument`, and `error` are called when the parser finds the end of a tag or document, or when an invalid sequence is discovered.

[This example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.xml.parsers/BasicSax.html) shows how to use a SAX parser.  The key is that the `MyHandler` class extends the `DefaultHandler` class (which implements the `ContentHandler` interface) and overrides the empty implementations of each callback method.

Think of it this way: the Java `SAXParser` class knows how to parse XML documents but when it discovers things of interest it relies on some handler class to know what to do with them.  The `DefaultHandler` class is a helper implementation which you can extend to pay attention to the interesting things.

Comment: THANKS maerics can u tell me how to parse a local xml file..then defaulthandler class not required

Answer (score 0):

You could use a ContentHandler directly (see below) instead of extending the DefaultHandler if you want.  I believe this level of SAX parsing is available on the Android platform.

```
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        xr.setContentHandler(new MyContentHandler());
        xr.parse("input.xml");
    }

    private static class MyContentHandler implements ContentHandler {

        public void setDocumentLocator(Locator locator) {
        }

        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        }

        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
        }

        public void startPrefixMapping(String prefix, String uri)
                throws SAXException {
        }

        public void endPrefixMapping(String prefix) throws SAXException {
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            System.out.println("START " + qName);
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            System.out.println("END " + qName);
        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
        }

        public void ignorableWhitespace(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
        }

        public void processingInstruction(String target, String data)
                throws SAXException {
        }

        public void skippedEntity(String name) throws SAXException {
        }

    }

}
```